# Define one to many sequelize include Query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I am trying to create three models with one to many relationships in Sequelize.

User, Post and Comment.

User - 1:M - Post
Post - 1:M - Comment

When I Query All posts I want to include comments associated with the post as well. I am not able to achieve it. Below is the code. Can anyone extend help I am really confused with associations now.

**User model**

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
userId: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull:false
},
userName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
userAuthId: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
userImage: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
role: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
})
```

**Post Model**

```
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
postId: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull:false
},
title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
postContent: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
},
postImage: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
type: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
}
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
})
```

**Comments**

```
const Comment = sequelize.define('Comments', {
commentId: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull:false
},
comment: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
}
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
})
```

**Associations**

```
Post.belongsTo(User, {
  as:'creator_id'
})

Post.belongsTo(User, {
  as:'parent_for'
})

Post.hasMany(Comment, {
  as: 'comments'
})

Comment.belongsTo(Post)

Comment.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'commentedUser',
  foreignKey: 'userId'
})
```

Desired Result

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "postId": "e1a7cc53-0376-43b6-b88b-9f51d95327b2",
            "title": "New psoit",
            "postContent": "e fed jefweef",
            "postImage": "url",
            "type": "regular",
            "createdAt": "2021-07-07T07:40:24.095Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-07T07:40:24.095Z",
            "creatorIdUserId": "14e72aac-8258-4533-a640-e41d78380084",
            "parentForUserId": "08c781fa-ce27-43f5-aa16-de3e35218765",
            "creator_id": {
                "userId": "14e72aac-8258-4533-a640-e41d78380084",
                "userImage": "url",
                "userName": "example@gmail.com"
            },
            "comments": [            
             {
                "commentId": "05d2c385-45d5-4259-9aef-803cc8750982",
                "comment": "commt eds",
                "createdAt": "2021-07-07T07:43:32.584Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-07-07T07:43:32.584Z",
                "postId": "e1a7cc53-0376-43b6-b88b-9f51d95327b2",
                "userId": "14e72aac-8258-4533-a640-e41d78380084"
              }
            ]          
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you want to have a join/relational database,

you can do as well as this, to have a many to many, use (hasMany)

#it means your post has many comments or likes and so on.

```
  Post.hasMany(models.User, {
  onDelete: "cascade",
});
```

**this is your code and the above code is what I suggest to you!**

```
    Post.belongsTo(User, {
  as:'creator_id'
})
```